# How do I remove extra bits of text from the code?

Tags: php, web

I am trying to insert 2 horizontal rules on the front page of a website. One is above a section and the other is bellow the section.
I have the class of the hr lines but when try working with it it doesn't show up on the page unless I type a character, in this case I typed a dot. No matter what I do to try to make the dot disappear or not use it I also lose the hr lines (I tried commenting them out).
Here is the code (divs containing the lines above and below and the section itself):

```
<div class="not-front hr">         
.
<hr />
</div>        
<div class="grid_11 footercontent">
<?php
    $block = module_invoke("views","block_view","engineering_solutions-block");
     print render($block['content']);
?>
</div>
<div class="not-front hr">  
.
<hr />
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to add width?

Comment: What is the CSS for the classes `.not-front` and `.hr`?  Because this should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ytrwz/

Comment: would it be an absurd solution to just give your div a width and a border and forget the hr?

Comment: Is this in all browsers?

Comment: i don't think <hr /> is a valid html tag. xhtml isn't usually processed well by browsers. try <hr></hr>

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: `<hr/>` (and `<br/>`) work fine for me.

Comment: the only difference between `<br>` and `<br />` or `<hr>` and `<hr />` is that in XHTML the tag is not self closing, thats where the slash originated, either way techinically works in HTML5, however i remember reading somewhere that `<br />` is bad, if i find the source ill update this comment.

Comment: @j_mcnally I am not sure what you mean. How can that be accomplished? Nick, yes, this was happening in all browsers. Thanks to your solution, I did manage to fix it. Now I have the hr lines where and how I wanted them. I still don't know why exactly I needed the dot for the lines to show up. Thank you all for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

couple things, try using `<hr>` also, without seeing your css, its hard to give a straight forward solution but as is based off of the problem you gave us this will fix it

```
<div class="not-front hr">         
<span style = "display:none;">.</span>
<hr>
</div>        
<div class="grid_11 footercontent">
<?php
    $block = module_invoke("views","block_view","engineering_solutions-block");
     print render($block['content']);
?>
</div>
<div class="not-front hr">  
<span style = "display:none;">.</span>
<hr>
</div>
```

**As a side note** it is typically considered bad practice to used spaces in `<div>` names

Comment: If the `.` is needed to position the `<hr/>` correctly, I'm not sure hiding it won't just break it again.

Comment: `display:none` will keep the `.` there if the place needs to be held in the end, `visibility:hidden` will also work

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you for your replies. @Nick I have tried your solution and it has worked with visibility:hidden.

Comment: glad i could be of assistance, if this helped you, mark it so with the checkmark by the vote counter.